# Como criar um serviço do Windows na instalação

Tags: delphi, instalador, windows-service

Vou distribuir minha aplicação feita em Delphi através de um instalador padrão criado com o Install Shield, mas ela necessita criar um serviço do Windows para funcionar. Sei com criar esse serviço manualmente, mas não como criá-lo pelo o Install Shield.

Por favor alguém pode me explicar como criar um serviço do Windows usando o Install Shield?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você poderia usar a ferramenta `installutil.exe` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/50614e95(v=vs.110).aspx); ele seria instalado temporariamente junto com o restante da aplicação, e no final da instalação, o instalador poderia executar a linha de comando necessária para subir o serviço. Feito isto, o installutil poderia ser apagado.

Comment: Me desculpe, achei que estava claro quando disse não sabia como fazer via Install Shield. vou reformular a pergunta.